# JPA: @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn or @JoinColumn + @Id

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have user class with @Entity annotation.

```
@Entity
public class User{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

private String firstName;
private String lastName;

}
```

And i need to create another table with User details.
It must be linked to User_id and don't have it's own id just:
`user_id` `phone_number` `address`

So, now i use this:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Data
public class UserDetails{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private User user;

    private String address;
    private String phone;
}
```

But i have a question: Why i use this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(nullable = false)
private Long id;
```

if

```
@OneToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private User user;
```

makes user_id for me?

If i delete Id field i have an error: No identifier specified for entity: test.UserDetails, but hey! @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn creates identifier for this entity.

Maybe i should use @Id + @JoinColumn instead of @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a part of the specification. `@Entity` always must have an `@Id`. In this example you don't even need `(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` as the key is given by parent entity (so there is no need to use any strategy for it's generation).

Comment: Sorry, i wont create a new question for this, but i need your help, tell me please, how can i save User and UserDetails to my database?

Comment: Here's something that might help: https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa

Answer (score 6):

As `@Entity` must always have an `@Id`, you could use the following snippet to map the both entities

```
@Id
@Column(name="user_id")
private Long id;

@OneToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
private User user;
```

Comment: doesn't work, Table [user_details] contains logical column name [`user_id`] referring to multiple physical column names